# Sorting strings in an array without using any built in sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I am in a JavaScript class and one of my assignments gives me a driver class and txt file full of strings. I have to make a class with three methods that sort the list by amount of vowels, consonants, and word length respectively and it will print out 3 different arrays at the end. I am not allowed to use any built in sorting methods, such as Array.sort. How do I this?

I have tried copying the string array and after that is when I get stumped.

Comment: They are asking you to implement a [Sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: Also, Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages.

Comment: How long are these strings?

Comment: They're only one word each, but it's an entire array of multiple random words.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the strings is small, you can use counting sort which has linear time complexity in the size of the array (taking the maximum string length as a constant).

```js
function countingSort(arr, countFn, maxStrLen = 100) {
  const counts = Array(maxStrLen + 1).fill(0);
  for (const x of arr) ++counts[countFn(x)];
  for (let i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) counts[i] += counts[i - 1];
  const res = Array(arr.length);
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    res[--counts[countFn(arr[i])]] = arr[i];
  return res;
}
const vowelCount = str => str.match(/[aeiou]/ig)?.length ?? 0;
const consonantCount = str => str.length - vowelCount(str);
const charCount = str => str.length;
const words = ['beneficiary', 'late', 'courtesy', 'momentum', 'short', 'prestige', 'stake', 'mud', 'wrist'];
console.log(...countingSort(words, vowelCount));
console.log(...countingSort(words, consonantCount));
console.log(...countingSort(words, charCount));
```